# Oracle copy data between databases honoring relationships

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a question regarding the oracle copy command:
  Is it possible to copy data between databases (were the structure is the same) and honor relationships in one go without(!) writing procedures?

To be more precise:
  Table B refers (by B.FK) to table A (A.PK) by a foreign key (B.FK -> A.PK; no relationship information is stored in the db itself). The keys are generated by a sequence, which is used to create the PK for all tables.

So how to copy table A and B while keeping the relationship intact and use the target DBs sequence to generate new primary keys for the copied data (i cannot use the "original" PK values as they might already be used in the same table for a different dataset)?

I doubt that the copy command is capable to handle this situation but what is the way to achieve the desired behavior?

Thanks
Matthias

Comment: The copy command is a sql*plus -only command.  Not part of SQL.  Copying tables with sequences to another database can be a pain.  Not sure how much data you have or how often you need to do it.  There are various methods to do this.  You could create a temp table to store the old sequences and map to new sequences in the new database, then write a function to do a replace in an insert statement.  Too long to try to comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has several different ways of moving data from one database to another, of which the SQL*Plus `copy` command is the most basic and the least satisfactory.  Writing your own replication routine (as @OldProgrammer suggests) isn't much better.

You're using 11g, so move into the 21st century by using [the built-in Streams functionality](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/information-management/streams-fov-11g-134280.pdf).

There is no way to synchronize sequences across databases.  There is a workaround, which is explained by [the inestimable Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:14672061404704#35065919915927).

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer db links and then use sql insert statements to copy over data.
In your scenario , first insert data of Table A using DB link and then table. If you try otherway round, you will error.

For info on DB link , you canc heck this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm